# variables a partir de un array javascript

Tags: javascript, array, variables

```
array citas = [
          {id: 1, precio:null, fecha: "2022-05-24 09:00:00", especialidad: 'medicina general'},
          {id: 2, precio:21333, fecha: "2022-04-24 09:00:00", especialidad: 'cardiologia'},
         {id: 3, precio:null, fecha: "2022-06-10 09:00:00", especialidad: 'medicina general'},
         {id: 4, precio:30000, fecha: "2022-05-24 09:00:00", especialidad: 'medicina general'},
         {id: 5, precio:26000, fecha: "2022-01-04 09:00:00", especialidad: 'medicina general'} ];
```

hola a todos tengo el siguiente array en javascript es mucho mas largo esto es una muestra deseo a partir de esto **sacar unas variables de los costos de la cita medica por mes** por ejemplo si hay dos citas en enero que se sumen cuanto valen y asi con las demas para sacar los costos o ingresos por mes con lo referente a las citas.

```
var precioCitas   = 0;
var nroCitas = 0;
const nroCitasPorMes = {}; 

         citas.forEach(cita => {
    // Forzar entero (null = 0)
    let precio = parseInt(cita.custom_service_price) || 0;
    precioCitas += precio;
    nroCitas ++;
    const mes = new Date(cita.start_date).getMonth() // obtener el número del mes
    // registrar la cita en el diccionario
    nroCitasPorMes[mes] = (nroCitasPorMes[mes] ?? 0) + 1
});

var citasJan =parseInt(nroCitasPorMes[0]) || 0;
var citasFeb =parseInt(nroCitasPorMes[1]) || 0;
var citasMar =parseInt(nroCitasPorMes[2]) || 0;
var citasApr =parseInt(nroCitasPorMes[3]) || 0;
var citasMay =parseInt(nroCitasPorMes[4]) || 0;
var citasJun =parseInt(nroCitasPorMes[5]) || 0;
var citasJul =parseInt(nroCitasPorMes[6]) || 0;
var citasAug =parseInt(nroCitasPorMes[7]) || 0;
var citasSep =parseInt(nroCitasPorMes[8]) || 0;
var citasOct =parseInt(nroCitasPorMes[9]) || 0;
var citasNov =parseInt(nroCitasPorMes[10]) || 0;
var citasDec =parseInt(nroCitasPorMes[11]) || 0;
```

esto es algo parecido pero solo suma la cantidad de citas por mes no se como asociar dicha cantidad al precio de cada cita segun el mes

Comment: Una cosa es lo que necesitas, y otra lo que has hecho para conseguirlo, y en tu pregunta lo siento pero no parece que hayas hecho nada, por lo tanto no podemos ayudarte a reparar nada tampoco.  Léete [ask] para aprender a formular preguntas que requieren de una investigación previa que no parece que hayas realizado, y [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio y [example] para aprender a poner el código necesario que nos permita reproducir tu problema (repito, ahora no tienes ninguno, tan solo que no lo has hecho aun y nos estás pasando la tarea a nosotros)

Comment: hola si disculpa tienes razon ya agregue mas info tengo un ciclo que hace algo similar pero solo calcula la cantidad de citas por mes pero no se como asociarla con los precios de las cita cada objeto tiene fecha y su precio pero no se como podria asociar ambos datos para crear variables a apartir de ello

Comment: Perdona que sea tan quisquilloso, pero siguen habiendo problemas en tu pregunta, pues la tienes muy descuidada. 1) En tu extracto del array citas todas las fechas estan mal escritas, pues pones `fecha "2022-05-24 09:00:00"`, y deberian separarse con **:**, o sea, `fecha: "2022-05-24 09:00:00"`. 2) La propiedad **especiallidad** supongo que deberia ser **especialidad**. 3) `precioCitas` lo defines como constante y luego intentas modificar su valor, eso esta mal 4) Idem con `nroCitas` 5) Esta línea tiene errores de sintaxis: `nroCitasPorMes[mes] = (nroCitasPorMes[mes] ?? 0) + 1`

Comment: nroCitasPorMes[mes] = (nroCitasPorMes[mes] ?? 0) + 1 esto lo hacia ya que hay varias citas que su precio o valor estan en null entonces con esto forzaba a que se convirtiera en entero y se pasara a 0

Comment: En resumen, lo que requieres es la suma de precios de cita por mes? Si es así puedo responder a la pregunta, solamente que mi método es algo ineficiente, ya tu podrías arreglarlo más.

Comment: @eduinfabianardilaruiz pues es curioso porque ese cacho de codigo me lo marca en rojo, en cambio funciona, ok

Comment: Más cosas a cambiar en la pregunta. Dado tu array inicial debes cambiar esto: `cita.custom_service_price` por esto `cita.precio`, y esto `cita.start_date` por esto: `cita.fecha`

Comment: en realidad asi se llaman las propiedades pero para el ejemplo puse precio y fecha para simplificar mas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```js
var citas = [{
    id: 1,
    precio: 20,
    fecha: "2022-05-24 09:00:00",
    especialidad: 'medicina general'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    precio: 21333,
    fecha: "2022-04-24 09:00:00",
    especialidad: 'cardiologia'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    precio: null,
    fecha: "2022-06-10 09:00:00",
    especialidad: 'medicina general'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    precio: 30000,
    fecha: "2022-05-24 09:00:00",
    especialidad: 'medicina general'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    precio: 26000,
    fecha: "2022-01-04 09:00:00",
    especialidad: 'medicina general'
  }
];

const precioCitas = {};
var nroCitas = 0;
const nroCitasPorMes = {};

citas.forEach(cita => {
  nroCitas++;
  let precio = parseInt(cita.precio) || 0;
  const mes = new Date(cita.fecha).getMonth() // obtener el número del mes
  precioCitas[mes] = (precioCitas.hasOwnProperty(mes)) ? precioCitas[mes] + precio : precio
  nroCitasPorMes[mes] = (nroCitasPorMes.hasOwnProperty(mes)) ? nroCitasPorMes[mes] + 1 : 1
});

console.log(nroCitasPorMes)
console.log(precioCitas)
```

Básicamente utilizo métodos parecidos a lo que ya tenias para hacer la suma, solo que he cambiado la sintaxis un poco para que se lea mejor.

Con este código sigues teniendo ambas cosas, la suma de las citas por mes y la suma de los precios de cada cita por mes, representados en los console.log del final, que dan como resultados:

```
{
  0: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 2,
  5: 1
}
{
  0: 26000,
  3: 21333,
  4: 30020,
  5: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución que plantee fue la siguiente:

```js
let citas = [
            {id: 1, precio:1500, fecha:   "2022-05-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
            {id: 2, precio:21333, fecha: "2022-04-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'cardiologia'},
            {id: 3, precio:1600, fecha: "2022-06-10 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
            {id: 4, precio:30000, fecha: "2022-05-24 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'},
            {id: 5, precio:26000, fecha: "2022-01-04 09:00:00", especiallidad: 'medicina general'} ]

            let ene = new Array()
            let feb = new Array()
            let mar = new Array()
            let abr = new Array()
            let may = new Array()
            let jun = new Array()
            let jul = new Array()
            let ago = new Array()
            let sep = new Array()
            let oct = new Array()
            let nov = new Array()
            let dic = new Array()

            citas.forEach( (cita, index) => {

                let mesPorFechaParseada = new Date(cita.fecha).getMonth()+1

                if(mesPorFechaParseada == 1) ene.push(cita.precio)
                if(mesPorFechaParseada == 2) feb.push(cita.precio)
                if(mesPorFechaParseada == 3) mar.push(cita.precio)
                if(mesPorFechaParseada == 4) abr.push(cita.precio)
                if(mesPorFechaParseada == 5) may.push(cita.precio)
                if(mesPorFechaParseada == 6) jun.push(cita.precio)
                if(mesPorFechaParseada == 7) jul.push(cita.precio)
                if(mesPorFechaParseada == 8) ago.push(cita.precio)
                if(mesPorFechaParseada == 9) sep.push(cita.precio)
                if(mesPorFechaParseada == 10) oct.push(cita.precio)
                if(mesPorFechaParseada == 11) nov.push(cita.precio)
                if(mesPorFechaParseada == 12) dic.push(cita.precio)

            })

            function sumaArray(array) {
                let suma = 0

                array.map( elemento => suma = suma + elemento)

                return suma
            }

            console.log("el array de mayo:",may)
            console.log("la suma del array de mayo: ",sumaArray(may))
```

Como te dije, se puede optimizar más, pero lo dejo a tu criterio.